# Exist-db text module for xquery not working

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I've recently discovered this module for xquery on exist db [here](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/text&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.text.TextModule). There are few methods that I would need to use, but I fail to use them properly. I have a series of test xml files in one collection, and they are all in this form

```html
<root>some string</root>
```

I am trying to use function `text:fuzzy-match-all` like this:

```html
xquery version "3.0";

for $doc in collection('/db/testCollection')
return text:fuzzy-match-any($doc,'test')
```

and I recive empty array as result, and I have at least one xml file that has `test` for value. I have also tried function `text:fuzzy-index-terms` like this

```html
xquery version "3.0";

text:fuzzy-index-terms("test")
```

and again, I receive no results at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy full-text index was removed from eXist-db some years ago.

You should take a look at the documentation for the Lucene Full-Text index for eXist-db: http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/lucene.xml

Comment: I'm aware of lucene, but there is a bug in there and I'm trying to make a workaround for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you would be better to upgrade. The version you are using is now EOL.